# Delete some dots on the beginning of a string in python

Tags: python, regex, string

I have some strings which starts with dots, and I want to delete it. Which is the best way.
And if the next caracter isn't a "/" add it.
I'm new in python and I've been trying to do something like this to erase dots but there is a syntax error.

```
while (re.match(r'\.*', url[0]).end()) = 0:
   url = url[1:]
```

- ..../xxx  ---> /xxx
- .xxx      ---> /xxx
- ..ab      ---> /ab
- /ab       ---> /ab
- ca        ---> /ca

This is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Maybe the syntax error is that you're using `=` instead of `==` for comparison?

Comment: To remove dots from the left end of  a string: new = old.lstrip(".") should work wonders.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To get rid of the dots:

```
mystr = '...../your_string'
mystr = '/' + mystr.lstrip('./')
```

and the result should be:

> /your_string

regardless of whether it begins with dots or slashes (they all will be replaced with single slash).

Answer (score 5):

Try with:

```
badUrl = "..../xxx"
url = "/" + badUrl.lstrip("./")
```

It will remove all dots and slashes from the beggining of your strings - and then we add slash manually.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend `url.lstrip(".")` to remove the dots, then

```
if not url[0] == '/':
    url="/"+url
```

to add the slash.

Comment: If the string can ever end in a dot this solution will also remove a trailing dot.

Comment: That should probably be `url.lstrip('.')` if there's a chance that there could be trailing dots that _shouldn't_ be removed.

Comment: @MichaelCOconner Thanks for spotting the typo. fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Has anyone considered using `lstrip('./')` ?

OK, `lstrip` doesn't *formally* answer his question as asked (since it will remove all dots and slashes, whereas intermixtures of dots and slashes should be ignored and multiple slashes should be preserved -- according to my literal reading of the post).

For that, you'd have to go with @ewok's solution.